# Tensorflow: How to add bias to ouputs from RNN where the sequences have varying length

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

First let me explain the input and target values of the RNN. My dataset consists of sequences (e.g. 4, 7, 1, 23, 42, 69). The RNN is trained to predict the next value in each sequence. So all values except the last are input, and all values except the first are target values. Each value is represented as a 1-HOT vector.

I have a RNN in Tensorflow where the outputs from the RNN (tf.dynamic_rnn) are sent through a feedforward layer. The input sequences have varying length, so I use the sequence_length parameter to specify the length of each sequence in a batch. The output from the RNN layer is a Tensor of outputs for each timestep. Most sequences have the same length, but some are shorter. When shorter sequences are sent through, I get additional all-zero vectors (as a padding).

The problem is that I want to send the output from the RNN layer through a feedforward layer. If I add bias in this feedforward layer, then the additional all-zero vectors become non-zero. With no bias, only weights, this works fine, since the all-zero vectors are not affected by multiplication. So without bias, I can set the target vectors as all-zero as well and thus they will not affect the backward pass. But if bias is added, I don't know what to put in the padded/dummy target vectors.

So the network looks like this:

```
[INPUT (1-HOT vectors, one vector for each value in the sequence)]
                      V
[GRU layer (smaller size than the input layer)]
                      V
[Feedforward layer (outputs vectors of the same size as the input)]
```

And here is the code:

```
# [batch_size, max_sequence_length, size of 1-HOT vectors]
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, n_classes])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, max_length, n_classes])
session_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

outputs, state = rnn.dynamic_rnn(
    rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_hidden),
    x,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    sequence_length=session_length
    )

layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes])),
         'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

# Flatten to apply same weights to all timesteps
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, n_hidden])

prediction = tf.matmul(output, layer['weights']) # + layer['bias']

error = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the bias, but mask out the non-relevant sequence elements from the loss function.

See an [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py#L307) from the im2txt project:

```
weights = tf.to_float(tf.reshape(self.input_mask, [-1])) # these are the masks

# Compute losses.
losses = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, targets)
batch_loss = tf.div(tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(losses, weights)),
                      tf.reduce_sum(weights),
                      name="batch_loss") # Here the irrelevant sequence elements are masked out
```

Also, for generating the mask see the function [`batch_with_dynamic_pad`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/im2txt/im2txt/ops/inputs.py#L126) in the same project, under ops/inputs

Comment: That works! Thank you. 
However, when I compute losses it has shape (200, 9), or (batch_size, sequence_length-1). Therefore I removed the `tf.reshape` when creating `weights`. Which means both `weights` and `losses` have shape (200, 9). Does this give me the correct result, or do I need to do reshape on both?